# Yoast SEO Breadcrumbs, Custom Post Type Not Working

Tags: wordpress, breadcrumbs

I've set up a custom post type on my blog.  On the individual posts, the Yoast SEO breadcrumbs don't seem to link to the parent post type.  For example, you can see in this entry...

http://thesoundtestroom.com/app_entry/beathawk

The home and parent links are styled correctly (orange), and the parent link is correct.  So why is it not displaying as a link?

Answer (score 0):

It is displayed as a link, but there is a `<div>` layer above it.

You can solve this with CSS...

1. Change .appStore-wrapper from margin-top: -30px to -10px

   .appStore-wrapper {
     margin-top: -10px;
   }
2. Remove the first empty frame in the HTML or add:

   .appStore-wrapper div:first-child {
     display: none;
   }